# How would I go about the proof of $e^x$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I am being asked to prove $$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{x^k}{k!} + \frac{1}{n!} \int_{0}^{x} e^t(x-t)^n \text{d}t$$ for $n = 1$, then to prove it by induction for $n = n + 1$, assuming it works for the base case of $n$. I proved the equation for $n = 1$ as such:

$$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{x^k}{k!} + \frac{1}{n!} \int_{0}^{x} e^t(x-t)^n \text{d}t$$
$$e^x = \frac{x^0}{0!} + \frac{x^1}{1!} + \int_{0}^{x} e^t(x-t) \text{d}t$$

Solving the integral by integration of parts, we get $e^x - x - 1$.

$$e^x = x + 1 + e^x - x - 1 = e^x$$

The identity holds for n = 1. However, when attempting to plug in $n + 1$ for n, I ran into difficulties trying to solve the integral. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is your definition of $e^x$. You have defined it as $$e^x=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$ or in another way?

Comment: @Marco i have it defined with the integral specifically -- i'd rather not try to prove it with that definition of $e^x$

Comment: The integration by parts idea is a good idea, generally speaking. Ignore all the rest of it for now, and try hitting the integral$$\int_0^x e^t(x - t)^n \, \mathrm{d}t$$with IBP, so that you integrate the $(x - t)^n$, and differentiate $e^t$.

Comment: Note that this is simply the Taylor formula with integral remainder, applied to the function $x\to e^x$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By induction you can prove
$$
\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^x e^t(x-t)^n dt= e^x-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}
$$
You have proved the case $n=1$. Let's assume it is true for $n-1$. Then, by integrating by parts,
$$
\int_0^x e^t(x-t)^n dt= - \frac{x^n}{n!} + \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^x e^t (x-t)^{n-1}dt
$$ and the result follows by the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Yes, I got up to that part. What I'm not sure of is how you can get that result by the "induction hypothesis" you mentioned. To me, I just see that integral as something which needs to be integrated again, and that results in another integral which needs to be integrated.


Also, you have $e^t$ left over. This isn't equal to $e^x$, no?

Comment: The induction hypotesys is that $$\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^x e^t (x-t)^{n-1} dt=e^x - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{x^k}{k!}$$
You have proved that $$\int_0^x e^t (x-t)dt$= e^x-x-1$$ so you have finished. The $e^t$ is my mistake. Thanks for noticing it